# Windows Azure, MVC 4.0 Application how to maintain the state? Is this the best practice to use TempData?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I m working on Windows Azure, MVC 4.0 Application. I want maintain the state between controller and view. I avoided using **Session**. But I am using **TempData**. Is this the best practice to use **TempData**?

Anybody knows Please let me know.

**Edited**
I have filters(that is Lambda expression) in the page. After applying filters, Grid will get populated. While paging I would like to maintain that Lambda expression and apply in order to paging logic work in the server side. I m not able to pass in to the model. I am using MVC kendo grid Ajax paging. Thats the why I am using TempData.

what happens when we have more than one webserver? Will the **TempData** get lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData uses Session by default so that's probably not what you want. Could you explain in more detail for what purpose and how long you want to maintain this state?

Comment: marcind, I have filters(that is Lambda expression) in the page. After applying filters, Grid will get populated. While paging I would like to maintain that Lambda expression and apply in order to paging logic work in the server side.

Comment: Filtering should be happening in your controller not your view.  You should pass your filter condition with your Model data back to the controller each time you change a page.

Comment: Marcind, yes you right. The drawback of using TempData is that it uses the SessionState for storing data. This means, that in Azure, where the request can be redirected to any instance, the default TempData implementation does not work. MVC has lot of extensibility mechanisms and TempDataProvider is one of them. This link explains more about this http://vijayt.com/Post/Custom-TempDataProvider-for-Azure